# Generic firestore methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create many firestore queries with using soooo many `where` clause in a few services, here is example code:

```
let user = await db.collection('user');
    
if (firstName) {
    user = user.where("name", "==", firstname);
}

if (lastName) {
    user = user.where("lastName", "==", lastName);
}

//many many more where clause

return user.get();
```

I need to create something like this in a many places in my project, so now I have a question, Is there any possibility to create an one generic method to search in Firestore collections with using many `where` clause?

thanks for any help, i want to omit boilerplate in my project

Comment: There probably is, but can you edit your question a bit to clarify how you imagine calling this generic method?

Comment: I wanted to accomplish that same logic, i got stuck just like you. Can anyone help, please